# Which database design gives better performance?

Tags: sql, database-design, database-performance, database-normalization

I want to `select` to retrieve `person` and also further make some inserts, deletes and updates.

If I want retrieve `person` who lives in `Brazil` what will be the best approach?

Make 2 foreign key `city` and `country` in table `person`:

```
Person(id, name, profession, **id_country**, **id_city**)   
cities (id, city, **id_country**)  
countries (id, country)
```

or just one foreign key of `cities` in table `person` and a other foreign key `county` in table `cities`

```
Person(id, name, profession, **id_city**)   
cities (id, city, **id_country**)   
countries (id, country)
```

or make a **view** like the first option?

For inserting, deleting and updating data, are they still the best tables? No difference in performance ? Also I'm confused, what can affect performance in a schema?

Comment: How do you measure "best" ?

Comment: in term of performance. and other criteria if they can help me

Comment: And what are you trying to perform? Inserts? Deletes? updates? specific queries?

Comment: i want now just make some search query `select`. and if you want give all the cases for Inserts, Deletes and updates.

Comment: Performance is a property of commands that retrieve or modify data, not a property of how data is stored.  You should clarify your question with examples of queries that you want to perform well, as well as estimates of the sizes of the various tables.

Comment: for example if i want retrieve person who lives in `Brazil` what will be the best approach ?

Comment: For your example the best solution would be Person(id, name, profession, country, city)  :)

Comment: so if i have other table the best way is to link them with the main table as foreign key ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is very similar to the one you made yestarday:

[Create many tables or just one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24183655/create-many-tables-or-just-one/24183736#24183736)

The answer is also similar - that depends on what you want to achieve. Both solutions could work and both have pros and cons and one should do a little trade-off analysis **in the light of the specific situation**. Out of this context is not possible to answer your question.

The only difference I see in both version is foreign key id_country in Person table:

Person(id, name, profession, ****id_country****, id_city)
cities (id, city, id_country)
countries (id, country)

The question is "do we need it?"

So, the pros and cons of both solutions:

**1. Solution: With id_contry:**

- pros: easier retrival of a Person based on land (simpler query) and better performance of this query
- cons: more complex underlaying DB and more redundancy, more chance of inreoducing inconsiscenties in the DB, harder updates

**2. Solution: Without id_country:**

- pros: simpler and cleaner model, no redundancy, easier maintenance
- cons: slower performance and more complex query for retrival of a Person based on land (simpler query)

So, the 1st solution effectivelly gives you easier query structure and better performance for retrieving Persons by Country (what you wanted), but it has its cost (see pros and cons). On the other side, pragmatic thinking says that country-city data are quite stabile and not often changed and this fact goes in favor of the 1st solution.

If this denormalization and slight chance of inconsistencies something you can live with, you can take the 1st solution.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, data integrity is more important than performance, so denormalize<sup>1</sup> only if you have performed **measurements** on **representative amounts of data** and the results indicate a strong need for better performance. More often that not, a normalized schema will perform just fine, especially if you got your physical design right (such as indexing).

In this particular case, my hunch would be that the second (normalized) design will work just fine.

That being said, probably the most efficient design for a query: "which persons live in a given country" would look something like this:

[image]

And then [**cluster**](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-organized-clustered-index) the PERSON on its PK. This way, all persons belonging to the same COUNTRY_ID are stored **physically close** together in the database, dramatically reducing the I/O for the query above<sup>2</sup>.

On the other hand, you no longer use simple auto-increment mechanism to generate your CITY_NO and PERSON_NO, the secondary indexes on PERSON are expensive because of clustering leading to *other* queries becoming slower etc. So, this is not absolutely "better" than your second design, they just both have different strengths/weaknesses and you'll have to decide which is a better trade-off in your particular case.

---

*<sup>1</sup> Which prevents the database from "self-defending" itself from bad data. In your case, the first (denormalized) design would allow a person to reference a country that does not contain the city referenced by the same person.*

*<sup>2</sup> I/O tends to be the biggest cost for most queries.*

Comment: Why can't you use an auto-gen values for those columns?  What about them am I missing?  Granted that there would be "gaps", but they'd still be grouped by the leading elements of the key, meaning people in the same country/city would still be grouped together.

Comment: But if i let my DB normalized and i create views ? is it the best way ? create views will affect performance ?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Yes you could do that, but these "gaps" would either waste storage (if your DBMS has integers in variable-width representation), or make you run out of available values sooner (in fixed-width representation).

Comment: @Youssef Unless these views are materialized, no - views alone would not affect performance. A view is just a convenient way to store a query in the database itself, and generally speaking does not have a different performance from the (properly prepared) query. But don't take my word for it. Seriously, don't. Always measure yourself.

Comment: Okay, so you're doing an increment for every city/country combo, right?  What happens if a city moves to a different country?  Or a person to a different city?  And how do you plan to generate these ids?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Generate new NO. This can be done as `MAX(NO) + 1 WHERE COUNTRY_ID = ? ...`, but special care needs to be taken to avoid race conditions with concurrent transactions trying to do the same (e.g. through locking, or by retrying the operation after a key violation).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to achieve. In both cases you are entering redundant data. It is called denormalization. Second example of denormalization is called "Short-Circuit Keys":

```
Person(id, name, profession, **id_city**)   
cities (id, city, **id_country**)   
countries (id, country)
```

The result of that can produce fewer table joins when queries execute. First example is called "The star schema":

```
Person(id, name, profession, **id_country**, **id_city**)   
cities (id, city, **id_country**)  
countries (id, country)
```

The star schema consists of one or more fact tables referencing any number of dimension tables.  Star schema join logic is generally simpler than the join logic required to retrieve data from a highly normalized transactional schemas. This example is usually seen in data warehouse database design.

There is no impact on performance in any case, you can choose one or the other to retrieve the data that you need.

Comment: thanks for the explanation but for inserting, Deleting and updating data, they still the same ? no difference on performance ? also i'm confused what can affect the performance in a schema ?

Comment: For inserting, deleting and updating data, there should be a trigger defined on tables. To prevent so-called orphaned data. And inserting, deleting and updating redundant data is always a performance issue. You must decide between selecting and writing joins the easier way or having quicker insert, delete and update.

Comment: But if i let my DB normalized and i create views ? is it the best way ? create views will affect performance ?

Comment: Yes in some cases views can update performance, depending on what kind of view you are creating.

Comment: so if i use views it will not affect negatively the performance ?

Comment: You can create both solutions and post a question hire, which of the two is a better performance, with database design and some data in tables, then we will see. :)

Answer (score 1):

(Your original post did not address performance but normalization, but it has has many edits and "performance" was introduced, maybe because your comments have mentioned it.)

One of the *points* of the relational model is generic querying with automated implementation with automated optimization. **Ignore performance initially. Just make a straightforward design.** (Before which you must learn how to make one.) Ids have nothing to do with performance. Normalization has something to do with performance but since you should normalize to 5NF first that is moot. Foreign keys have something to do with performance but since you should be defining them for integrity their role in performance is moot. Proper designs enable later tuning.

Anyway performance is a tradeoff of factors and if you do not know what sorts of things you want to do it is meaningless to discuss performance. (Or if you do not even know what those sorts of things are.) Also, performance-related properties must be measured to even hold an opinion that manual optimization intervention is appropriate. (And again you would have to understand what those factors even are.)

When performance becomes a demonstrated issue because a particular application makes particular patterns of queries or updates then you can address performance. First via indexing and views to make those patterns perform better--always at the expense of others.

The sorts of things you are mentioning (and not mentioning) and the way you are mentioning them suggest that **you have misconceptions about performance** and its relation to design. Also that your understanding of relational structure, querying and DBMSs is extremely low. Until you learn much more about basic design **any advice you get about biasing for performance is misdirected**. So just forget about performance. **The main thing that adversely affects performance is premature concern for performance getting in the way of a straightforward design.**

A simplest design is

```
person(id, name, profession, city, country)
    -- person [id] is named [name] and practises [profession] in [city], [country]  
city (name, country) -- [name] uniquely names a city within country [country]
country (name) -- [name] uniquely names a country
```

This has certain keys and FKs, just declare them--which has nothing to do with performance. It is in 5NF.

You may come to understand that the following design (you can add relevant constraints) may be better for you than the previous one--which will have nothing to do with performance. Then you can move to it and offer the previous tables as views to old users--which will have nothing to do with performance.

```
person(id, name, profession, id_city)
    -- person [id] is named [name] and practises [profession] in [id_city]  
city (id, name, id_country) -- city [id] is named [name] and is in country [id_country]
country (id, name) -- country [id] is named [name]
```

Here id_country in person would violate 5NF since it would be functionally dependent on a non-key, id_city.

Comment: In real life, there may be multiple cities with the same name within the same country.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic Aw, you spoiled the surprise.