# Is it better to have multiple index or an index with multiple columns for join query where one column used at 'on' while the other used at 'where'?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, indexing

If I have

```
Select *  
from tbl_x x  
left join tbl_y y on x.a = y.a  
where y.b = 'iwantthisvalue'
```

should I create separate index for each idx(y.a) and idx2(y.b)
or should I create only one with 2 columns idx(y.a, y.b)?

Comment: I would say idx(y.b, y.a) would be better since y.b is in where condition which will be used to filter rows.

Comment: Ask your database using EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) for your SQL - statements. This will show you the query plan and execution time and gives you something to compare.

Comment: By the way, because of your WHERE condition the LEFT JOIN turns into an INNER JOIN.

Comment: [How to Optimize Queries in a Database - The Basics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3191623/3404097)
[What are your most common sql optimizations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1332778/3404097)
[When and why are database joins expensive?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/173726/3404097)
[Re SQL "performance".](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24196511/3404097) [Tips for asking a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271055/3404097) [Asking query performance questions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3034/43932)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are multiple rows with same value in `y.a` and multiple rows with same value in `y.b` - you can create one index for both `create index on y(a asc, b asc)`. The executor will look up first for `join` and then for `where` in joined result. If there are aggregate functions in `select` - add other columns in `include` of the index. The `group by` columns could also be "added" (not "included") to the index if it is used in the query. So the executor will look up for `join` after that for `where`, for `group by` and for `select` of "included".