# Join and aggregate two huge tables efficiently

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join, self-join

I have a huge table with over 1 million transaction records and I need to join this table to itself and pull all similar transactions within 52 weeks prior for each transaction and aggregate them for later use in an ML model.

```
select distinct a.transref, 
    a.transdate, a.transamount, 
    a.transtype,
    avg (b.transamount) 
        over (partition by a.transref,a.transdate, a.transamount,a.transtype) as avg_trans_amount
from trans_table a
inner join trans_table b
on a.transtype = b.transtype
and b.transdate <= dateadd(week, -52, a.transdate)
and b.transdate <= a.transdate
and a.transdate between '2022-11-16' and '2021-11-16'
```

the transaction table looks like this:

```
+--------+----------+-----------+---------+
|transref|trasndate |transamount|transtype|
+--------+----------+-----------+---------+
|xh123rdk|2022-11-16|112.48     |food & Re|
|g8jegf90|2022-11-04|23.79      |Misc     |
|ulpef32p|2022-10-23|83.15      |gasoline |
+--------+----------+-----------+---------+
```

and the expected output should look like this:

```
+--------+----------+-----------+---------+----------------+
|transref|trasndate |transamount|transtype|avg_trans_amount|
+--------+----------+-----------+---------+----------------+
|xh123rdk|2022-11-16|112.48     |food & Re|180.11          |
|g8jegf90|2022-11-04|23.79      |Misc     |43.03           |
|ulpef32p|2022-10-23|83.15      |gasoline |112.62          |
+--------+----------+-----------+---------+----------------+
```

Since each transaction may pull over 10,000 similar type records the query is very slow and expensive to run, therefore SQL Server failed to create the output table.

How can I optimize this query to run efficiently within a reasonable time?

Note: After failing to run the query, I ended up creating a stored procedure to split the original table `a` into smaller chunks, join it to the big table, aggregate the results and append the results to an output table and repeat this until the entire table `a` was covered. This way I could manage to do the job, however, it was still slow. I expect there are better ways to do it in SQL without all this manual work.

Comment: Please show some sample data with the expected result.

Comment: actually the only way I was able to successfully do this was by splitting the first table to smaller chunks, joining, aggregating, writing to a table and then appending the next chunk to it, however I think there must be better way of doing this if I don't want to do all this manual work.

Comment: Do you want to know about transactions that occurred within 52 weeks of each other ... 10 years ago? Seems like there should be a lower bounds condition to define the latest transactions of interest. And something to correlate transactions owned by a particular account/owner/user.

Comment: thanks, I have already filtered out the transactions in table a (lower bounds are already considered). I'd like to know how a transaction in a particular date is related to similar type transaction s n a window of time before that. it doesn't matter who did this transaction and from what account.

Comment: I doubt the table primary key is just these 2 columns `transtype` and `transdate` . By self joining the table on that 2 columns, you are killing the performance. Why don't you use a simple `GROUP BY` query ?

Comment: transref is the actual unique variable of the table. again I need to do some staticall calculations like avg, median, percentile over a window of time for each transaction.

Comment: Please provide your working code, your table and index definitions, and your actual execution plan which you can upload on [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan).

Comment: Whats 1MM - a mega-million?

Comment: This shows no research or understanding of performance issues--what it is asking about. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) Debug questions require a [mre]. [ask] [Help]

Comment: [Tips for asking a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271055/3404097) [Asking query performance questions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3034/43932) [How to Optimize Queries in a Database - The Basics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3191623/3404097)
[What are your most common sql optimizations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1332778/3404097)
[When and why are database joins expensive?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/173726/3404097) 
[Re SQL "performance".](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24196511/3404097)

Answer (score 0):

ok, I think I figured out what's causing the query to run tooslow. the trick is to avoid repetitive and unnecessary calculations by doing some group by first before doing the join.

```
with merch as (
    select transtype,
    dateadd(week, -52, transdate) as startdate,
    transdate as enddate),
    from trans_table 
    group by transtype, transdate),


summary as (
    select distinct transtype,
    stratdate, enddate, 
 avg(t.transamt) over (partition by 
 m.transtype, m.startdate, m.enddate) as avg_amt,


 percentile_cont(0.5) within group (order by t.transamt) over (partition by
 m.transtype, m.startdate, m.enddate) as median_amt

from merch as m
inner join trans_table as t
on m.transtype = t.transdate and
   t.transdate between m.starttype and
   m.enddate)



select t.*, s.avg_amt  s.median_amt
from trans_table t
inner join summary s
on t.transtype = s.transtype
and t.transdate = s.enddate
```