# Is there a way to represent relationship between a tuple and to a table in E-R diagram?

Tags: database, entity-relationship, rdbms, entity-attribute-value, database-metadata

I know this might sound a bit ridiculous, but I got a doubt that if we can represent relationship between two tables, how the two table's data is related, is there a way to represent relationship like, each registered user has a seperate pagelikes table. To make it more clear about my doubt, let me explain in this way, students enrolling for a few courses, say c, c++, java or others. Then, we can say:

Student -(enrols for)-  courses

which means that student x can register for courses like c, c++, java or courses can be enrolled by 1 or more students.

In the same way, can we, some how, represent the relationship like registered user 1 has a pagelikes_1 table created for him or her?

sample pics:
[user profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xvw9t.jpg)
[image]

[pagelikes of that user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xvw9t.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xvw9t.jpg)

Comment: Please give example tables and definitions including constraints and what a table row means. (Especially since your English is not very clear.) Why can't you use one table that is the union of yours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**
***Your question is more or less the canonical situation in which one must decide between DDL (Data Definition Language) vs [EAV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21714715/designing-an-eav-database-correctly-for-historical-data/23950836#23950836) (Entity-Attribute-Value).***

**Use one table if you can**

Normally, you would have one table which is the union of all the tables you are talking about. As for enrolments.

```
// student [student] is enrolled in [course]
Enrolment(student,course)
PK (student, course)
FK (student) to Student (student)
FK (course) to Course (course)

// user [user] likes page [page]
Likes(user,page)
PK (user, page)
FK (user) to User (user)
```

There isn't a standard ER way to indicate a table per entity instance, ie an association set per entity instance. That's because you would normally have one liked page table, as for enrolments.

**Constrain the user table and tables about tables**

There are "metadata" tables that describe the database itself. (Details depend on the DBMS.) There will be a table that I'll call Table with a column that I'll call tablename with a row for each database table, holding its name in tablename. The "relationship", ie constraint, that you want can be expressed between Table and a User table. (But not necessarily declaratively in a particular SQL DBMS.)

It's not clear exactly what relationship/constraint you want to record. Probably you want to say at least that if a table with a name like Likes_*user* exists then its user does. That is not a "relationship"/constraint of the kind that ER diagrams display, which are FKs (foreign keys). That cannot be expressed declaratively by most (but not all) SQL DBMSs. It is `NOT EXISTS(select tablename from Table where tablename like 'Likes_%' except select CONCAT('Likes_', user) as tablename from User)`.

You could calculate and store a user's tablename in a User column likestablename and declare a `FK Table (tablename) references User (likestablename)`. (Declare likestablename as a computed column, if your DBMS allows it.) If you could add a nullable user column to Table then you could declare 'FK Table (user) references User (user). But you can't because it's a system table. You could declare a view but SQL won't let you declare FKs in views.

You may also want every User user to have a tablename in Table tablename. That is 
`NOT EXISTS(select CONCAT('Likes_', user) as tablename from User except select tablename from Table where tablename like 'Likes_%')`.

If Table tablename values were just like the User user values then you could instead declare a FK User (user) references Table (tablename). Since they differ, you can use the User tablename technique to just declare a `FK User (tablename) references Table (tablename)`.

If you want both of these constraints then you want every user to have an exactly-1-to-exactly-1 (ie "1-to-1 correspondence") between *some* rows of two tables tables. That is not easy to do declaratively in most SQL DBMSs even for *all* rows because they won't allow FKs in both directions between tables. Normally you could handle the all-rows case by pairing them up in the same table. (Possibly involving views.) But here you can't because Table is a system table.

**If your `Likes_`*`user`* tables have different columns then it's DDL vs EAV**

You might want different columns in each of the tables. Then indeed you could have multiple Likes_*user* tables managed by DML and DDL, which is clear and uses the DBMS fully. But if in this different-columns case *after testing and costing* the DDL is inadequate you could use a single table along with multiple tables and/or null columns. These implement a technique "EAV" that is otherwise an anti-pattern since you lose a lot of DBMS functionality.