# RDBM dynamic table structure

Tags: database, rdbms

I am trying to create a dynamic table.

```
ID  |TABLE_NAME    | COLUMN_NAME| VALUE | CRITERIA_COLUMN | CRITERIA_VALUE
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   |PRODUCT_LIST  | HANDLE_FEE |  5    |  COUNTRY        |  AUSTRALIA
```

This shows which column needs to be updated.
This data translates to

```
UPDATE PRODUCT_LIST
SET HANDLE_FEE = 5
WHERE COUNTRY = 'AUSTRALIA'
```

But if I want to add more criteria like

```
UPDATE PRODUCT_LIST
SET HANDLE_FEE = 5
WHERE COUNTRY = 'AUSTRALIA'
AND STATE = 'WA'
```

How would you change the dynamic table to achieve this update statement?

Comment: You're trying to recreate a DBMS inside your DBMS. Why?

Comment: I need to record all update history. Table structure change often, so i want to make it dynamically so that I don't have to change anything.

Comment: How about recording all update history via a transaction log?

Comment: [To paraphrase Greenspun, any sufficiently complex EAV project contains an ad hoc, informally-specified, bug-ridden, slow implementation of half of a DBMS.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23950836/3404097)

Answer (score 0):

In relational theory and in SQL dbms in general, this "dynamic" table has a special name. It's called "table".

Using a table like this won't "record all update history". It will only record parts of update statements for whoever is using your front-end application.

Assuming that, by *update history*, you mean *all* the insert, update, and delete statements, that can only be done by auditing or logging.

For example, you can configure PostgreSQL to log all insert, update, and delete statements (and a few others) by setting `log_statement = mod` in the file postgresql.conf. You can configure SQL Server for [change data capture or change tracking](https://docsd.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/track-data-changes-sql-server). SQL Server also supports [C2 audit mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/c2-audit-mode-server-configuration-option) (deprecated) and [common criteria compliance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/common-criteria-compliance-enabled-server-configuration-option).

If you *must* go down the path you seem to have set for your employer--and that's a really, really bad idea--you would move the pieces of the WHERE clause to another table, set a foreign key reference "your_table_name", and assume that all related rows in the WHERE clause should be ANDed together. But then later accommodate the need to use OR sometimes. And again later accommodate arbitrary numbers and levels of nested parens. And again later accommodate the fact that you need to support more operators than just `=`. And again later . . .

Comment: Thanks for the [database-normalization] tagging. A while ago I added it to many recent [normalization]/[normalization] questions but  I mostly left the old tags when I didn't need to make space. (I have a [tag synonym proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/353819/3404097) re the latter which I thought would be a slam-dunk, I wonder why not.)