# Insert query for storing global site preferences in php and Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Can anyone recommend the best practice for storing general site preferences.
I want to store Site details in database like WordPress theme setting. Can any one can help??

**My Table:**

```
+------------------+--------------------+------------------+
|            id    | setting_key        | setting_value    |             
+------------------+--------------------+------------------+
|             1    | website_name       | Website Name     |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: What do you mean by general site preferences ? which kind of data do you store there ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best table design for application configuration or application option settings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387294/best-table-design-for-application-configuration-or-application-option-settings)

Comment: Like Wordpress meta values saving(Theme Setting)

Answer (score 0):

I know you want to store them in a mySQL db but have you considered putting them in the same place Laravel stores the configuration settings in the `'/config'` folder.

To do this create a file in the config folder called `settings.php` which will contain:

```
<?php

return [

    'website' => 'Website Name'

];
```

Then to access or modify the value:

```
// Get value
$website = Config::get('settings.website');

// Set value
Config::set('settings.website', 'New Website Name');
```