# Structuring a database to handle unknown name/value pairs

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, nvp

Here's the idea: I expect to be receiving thousands of queries, each containing a certain amount of name value pairs; these start off as associative arrays, so I have fairly good control over what can happen to the data. These NVPs vary dependent on the source. For example, if the source is "A", I could receive the array (in JSON for ease of explanation): `{'Key1':'test1','key2':'test2'}` but if the source was "B", I could receive `{'DifferentKey1':'test1','DifferentKey2':'test2'}` I'm selecting which keys I want to store in my database, so in this case I could only want to select `DifferentKey1` from source B's array, and discard the rest.

My main issue here is that these arrays could technically be completely unrelated content wise. They have a very general association (they're both arrays containing stats) but they're very different (in that the sources are different, ie. different games/sports).

I was thinking SQL: storing a table filled with games and their respective ids would be a good way of linking general NVP strings. For example:

```
Games table:
| id | name |
-------------
  1    golf
  2    soccer

NVP table
| id | game_id | nvp
   1      1      team1score=87;team2score=94;team3score=73;
   2      2      team1score=2;team2score=1;extratime=200;numyellowcards=4;
```

Hope that's clear enough. Do you see what I mean though? If there's an indeterminant amount of data that I may use, how can I structure a table? Thanks.

Edit: I guess I should note, obviously this set up WOULD work, however is it the best performance wise? Maybe not? I'm not sure, let's see what you guys can come up with!

Comment: looks like you re-invented the Key-Value Store...!

Comment: So what are you suggesting? Is this a commonly accepted way of doing things? I thought there might be a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL databases are great for highly relational data - but in a case like this where the data is not relational and there is no fixed schema, you might be better off using a NoSQL solution. There are a lot and I haven't used them enough to be sure what would work best for you. If your data can fit in RAM, then redis is great.

Comment: Would this type of solution be more efficient performance wise than what I've suggested? Is there another way you can think of that will relate this data?

Comment: In terms of performance - yes, a NoSQL solution should be very fast. Faster for large amounts of data than a SQL database, but that doesn't mean the SQL database will be slow. It might not be the best way of representing your data though, it's hard to know if it'd be a good thing to make your data more relational without knowing your domain a lot better. I would recommend you play with a NoSQL database for a bit, and see if it works well for your application.

Comment: In general, being good for handing these sort of entities with loose schema is a strong point for the NoSQL databases.

Answer (score 0):

The common way of storing name/value pairs in a relational database is known as ["Entity/Attribute/Value"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model). You'll find a [lot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870808/entity-attribute-value-database-vs-strict-relational-model-ecommerce) of [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494158/best-beginner-resources-for-understanding-the-eav-database-model?rq=1) on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066463/should-i-use-eav-model?rq=1).

It all depends on what your application wants to do with the data. Storing is it easy - querying is much harder.

If you're building a sports application, you are likely to have domain concepts you want to support - for football, show a league position based on games played. For golf, show the number of birdies or eagles. You will probably want to show all the games a particular team/player has played in a season.

Some things are easy to build in a relational database, and have amazing performance over huge data sets. Find the highest-scoring game ever, find the last game in the 1998 season, find all the games featuring player x - all a great fit, as long as you can build a schema that represents those domain concepts.

From what you write, it does sound like you will have a fixed number of sports; the data *coming in* to your system sounds like it's not particularly structured, but you should be able to structure that to a domain model. If that's true, I recommend building a relational schema that reflects the domain logic of each sport.

If that's not true - if you can't reason about the domain in advance - the relational model is a bad fit, and NoSQL is probably better. But you will run into the same problem - extracting meaning from name/value pairs is going to be hard!